# Is effective mass used in calculating kinetic energy of electron in semiconductor?

Tags: energy, electrons, mass, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is effective mass used in calculating kinetic energy of electron in semiconductor? I recall it was just used to take into account the internal forces so that expression of force fits well. But why
$E_k= \frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m_e^*}$ uses $m_e^*$ as effective mass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effective mass is not the real mass of electrons. For a free electron we don't need to consider effective mass, here electron's real mass can easily describe things.
But for electrons in solids (such as in semiconductor), it is easier to work with effective mass, because it enables one to proceed as if the electron was essentially free, so same mathematical procedures as used for free electron can be used.
That is why, as you wrote, kinetic energy of the electron can be expressed in terms of its effective mass, $E_k = \frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m^*}.$
Effective mass can be positive, zero and even negative.

This effective mass is actually a tensor, with the tensor components given by:
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{m^*}\right)_{ij}=\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial k_i\partial k_j}.
\end{equation}
You can see, the value of effective mass depends on the dispersion relation $(E$ vs $k)$ of the electron in the solid. That is, how energy of the electron is dependent on the wave vector.